# Installing F# in visual studio code

Tags: f#

I am trying to install F# with Visual studio code in Windows 10. I have installed dotnet framework first.

Then I have installed lonide-fsharp in visual studio code.

Then I have included the path of fsi in visual studio by clicking the Preferences->extensions->selected F# and Included the path.

Now in the visual studio code I typed ctrl+shift+p then I have typed fsi start, I am getting an error.

I tried with '/' and '\'. in the path. Every time I change I uninstalled the lonide and installed it again.

When I do fsi start ,F# should get started or what are all the other ways that I can make F# to start.

What is happening here is 'C:/Program Files/dotnet/sdk/3.0.100/FSharp/fsi the path does not exist'.

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure you have the latest version of VS Code and Ionide.

Then, if you install the .NET Core 3.0 SDK from https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download, then it should install fsi.exe to that path. And then F# Interactive should just work with Ionide without any other configuration needed.

Comment: The path I have given is not correct.I missed the colon.It should be C:/.../...